# Edit Text not showing value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have a column in the database of type double, now, i get the value and try to asign it to a number signed - number decimal Edit Text, I convert the value to String using kotlin toString method. However nothing is showing in the edit text. When I use a println method the value appears in the logcat. I dont know what to do. I have other inputs that show the text with no problem, however this type of edit text is not working for me.

This is the code I use to to start the activity:

```
        val recordEditButtonListener = View.OnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, AddEditRecordActivity::class.java)

            intent.putExtra(RECORD_ID, currentRecord.id)
            intent.putExtra(RECORD_CATEGORY, currentRecord.category)
            intent.putExtra(RECORD_AMOUNT, currentRecord.amount)
            intent.putExtra(RECORD_DATE, currentRecord.date)
            intent.putExtra(RECORD_DESCRIPTION, currentRecord.description)

            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_RECORD_REQUEST)
        }
```

and this is from the activity itself:

```
val amountText = intent.getDoubleExtra(RECORD_AMOUNT, 1.0).toString()
amount_input.setText(amountText)
```

This is the record table structure:

```
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Account::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("accountId"),
        onDelete = CASCADE,
        onUpdate = NO_ACTION
    )]
)
class Record(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int?,
    var amount: Double,
    var category: String,
    var description: String,
    var date: String,
    var recordImage: String,
    var recordImageDescription: String,
    var accountId: Int
)
```

This is the xml:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/category_spinner"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:hint="@string/record_amount_input_text" android:id="@+id/amount_input"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/record_select_date_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/date_text"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/amount_input"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amount_input"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/description_input" android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date_text"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/date_text" android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="@string/record_description_input_text"/>
```

Comment: Please supply the code you used to display the number in your EditText.

Comment: Please help me, I just have this problem with this type of input, the others are working fine.

Comment: Can you show your xml?

Comment: just added in the question.

Comment: Solved! I was overwriting the text input in the OnResume method with another text.